# Trying to get text on same line

Tags: html

OK, another quick question pertaining to this.  I took the advice and it works great, my dilemma now is that there is a space between the tables.

I was going to attach a file but I guess I don't have the rep too quite yet.

Anyways, if you can go to http://www.wholesalecabinets.us/Wall-Cabinets_c_524.html, you'll see what I mean. See how the line is close at the tops of the tables and there is a space before the line starts again?

I know, I know... something easy for you guys.

Sorry, I'm a newb and I don't have much HTML experience, but I need some help with a problem.

Currently I have a website that has a bunch of product.  I managed to get the products listing to be pretty close to what I want with the exception of one problem, I want the price to be on the same line as the [name] but to the far right.  Currently it is under the description to the far right.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

```
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="95%">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" class="item" style="width:75px;"><a href="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]&catid=[catid]"><img src="thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]&maxx=50&maxy=50" alt="[name]" border="0" /></a></td>
          <td class="item" align="left" valign="middle"><a href="product.asp?itemid=[catalogid]&catid=[catid]"><span class="item">[name]</span></a><br>
            <span class="item">[description]</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="item" align="right" valign="top"><span class="price">[ITEMPRICE]</span>   [product_quantity] 
            <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="[catalogid]" />
            <input type="text" size="2" name="qty-[counter]" value="0" /></td>
        </tr>
       <img src="assets/templates/[template]/images/div.png" alt="template" vspace="2" width="95%" height="1" />
      </table>
```

Comment: I suggest you look into CSS, that'll get you on the right path

Comment: Well you're in the right place for questions! Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete these two lines

```
         </tr>
         <tr>
```

You're inserting a new row, when all you want is a new column on the same raw.

Comment: Ok, it worked!  Thanks.  I knew it would be easy for the pros.

Comment: sorry - one more quick question pertaining to this.  There is a small space at the top of the table but a larger one at the bottom before the div.png run to separate all of the tables.  I took out the other /tr, thinking that there was another line put in before, but that didn't fix it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Firstly that img is wrong put there. It should be in a <tr><td> if inside the table, or put it outside the table. Secondly delete the rowspan="2" from the first td. Your issue might be browser specific or coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by putting the price td in the same row as the name td.

Answer (score 0):

The `<tr>` elements in your HTML are table rows.  What you're looking for are columns.  You cannot explicity define columns in HTML (HTML is one dimensional after all) but you can define td (table data) and th (table header) elements inside a row to effectively create a column. If you want your item name, description and price to all be on the same line, they need to be inside the same table row, represented separately as either `<td>` or `<th>` elements.